# VBA For each - loop order

Tags: vba, for-loop, each, shapes

In VBA, it's possible to loop through shapes. For example:

```
For Each shp In slide.Shapes
 shp.top=0
Next
```

The question is, which parameter is being used to determine the order of the loop and how can this parameter be set?

Answer (score 1):

edited after OP's clarification about his need of looping through shapes from the highest on the lowest

you can use `SortedList` object use `Shape` `Top` property as the `SortedList` key and the `Shape` object itself as its corresponding value:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim j As Long

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
        For Each shp In slide.Shapes
            .Add shp.Top, shp
        Next

        For j = 0 To .Count - 1 'list shapes from the highest to the lowest
            MsgBox .GetByIndex(j).Name & " - " & .getkey(j)
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: at Cymro, and my answer was _"most probably it's their order of appearance"_, as I could prove from some tests of mine. May be I should specify that by _order of appearance_ I mean the order by which they have been created

Comment: @Cymro, see edited answer to loop from the highest to the lowest shape

Comment: Well, the handle is already in the answer i.e.: .GetByIndex(j). So you can type: For j=0 to .count - 1 : MakeBold .GetByIndex(j) : next. You may consider marking the answer as accepted, thank you

Comment: If there are 2 objects with the same vertical position, your code fails, with this error "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'XX' Key being added 'XX' ". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the MicroSoft site:

[Shape.ZOrderPosition Property (PowerPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/shape-zorderposition-property-powerpoint)

The site says "**A shape's position in the z-order corresponds to the shape's index number in the Shapes collection.**".

I then did a short sort routine to set the z-order position based on the .top parameter of the shape:

```
For i = 2 To sld.Shapes.Count
  If sld.Shapes(i).Top < sld.Shapes(i - 1).Top _ 
  and sld.Shapes(i).ZOrderPosition > sld.Shapes(i - 1).ZOrderPosition Then_
  sld.Shapes(i).ZOrder msoSendBackward
Next i
```